# Expression to filter out elements with empty arrays using `jsonPath`

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jsonpath

I have a JSON payload of the form:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "list": [1], "name":"one"}, 
  {"id": 2, "list": [1,2], "name":"two"},
  {"id": 3, "list": [], "name":"three"}
]
```

And I want to filter out the element from the array the contains an empty `"list"` property.  In other words, I want to discard the element with `id=3` and process only the first and second element in my example above.

Currently, my filter looks like this:

```
<!-- ne == not equals -->
<int:filter id="filter" 
            input-channel="in" 
            output-channel="out" 
            expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$[*].list') ne '[]'"
            discard-channel="consoleOutputChannel" />
```

But this is not working, how should I indicate to my `expression` that I want to exclude elements with empty `list` properties?

Comment: use .length() ?

Comment: How would the syntax go? I think I already tried it and didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your expression to:

```
$.[?(@.list.length()> 0)]
```

- `[?(<expression>)]` : filter expression
- `@`                 : The current node being processed
  by a filter predicate
- `list.length()`     : the length of `list` array

More detail at [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Comment: I will try when I get back at my desk (tomorrow) and report back.. .thx

Comment: please look at [answer]

Comment: I don't understand why it is not provide an answer? But nvm, i will update more details..

Comment: do you think it's a good a idea to post a link which may become invalid?

Comment: what means invalid?

Comment: other word: "broken"

Comment: github link will be broken?

Comment: Links can be broken, yes. It could happen (i.e. what if they get DDoS'd? or the DNS is changed? or...) there are many reasons a site could become unavailable to some users (think Country restrictions) - it's always best to include relevant code into the answers and make them self-sufficient

Comment: BTW, I ended up splitting the payload before passing it to the filter and then applying the following expression: `#jsonPath(payload, '$.docSources.length()') > 0` - this worked as a charm **only** after splitting the array (not before) - thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Jerry06, I was able to do what I wanted but only ***after*** splitting the payload array.

This is the complete solution but I could only do it because of his help (thx) so the credits are to him.

My code now looks like this:

```
<!-- Split payload into individual messages -->
<int:splitter id="splitter"
                  input-channel="in"
                  output-channel="toFilter"
                  expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$.[*]')"/>

<!-- Filters out messages with empty array of list -->
<int:filter id="filter"
            input-channel="toFilter"
            output-channel="out"
            discard-channel="consoleOutputChannel"
            expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$.list.length()') > 0"/>
```