# Check JSONPath for empty string

Tags: jsonpath

I have the following JSON string:

```
{
  "myKey": "myValue"
}
```

I want to check whether this string is not empty. I can do this:

```
$.myKey
```

to get the value of myKey. I've tried changing it to

```
$.[?(@.myKey.length()>0)]
```

(as per this topic [Expression to filter out elements with empty arrays using `jsonPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883443/expression-to-filter-out-elements-with-empty-arrays-using-jsonpath)) or even this:

```
$.myKey.length()>0
```

but I get error that it is not a valid JSONPath expression.

I add "JsonPath Match" to the test step in my project. When I set it to

```
$.myKey
```

and press "Select from current", it works. For

```
$.[?(@.myKey != '')]
```

when I press "Select from current", I get

> "Invalid JsonPath expression"

I use SoapUI 5.4.0 but I don't know how to check its JsonPath implementation. I want to get false if string is empty.

How can I check whether myValue is empty or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The following jsonpath filter: `$.[?(@.myKey != '')]` will return the document if the attribute `myKey` is not an empty string.

You can verify this using the [Jayway JsonPath evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

If this ...

> How can I check whether myValue is empty or not?

... means something like: "I only want to return the document if myKey is populated" then the above jsonpath filter should suffice.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, even if it worked in JSONPath evaluator, it didn't work in SoapUI where I wanted to have it

Comment: SoapUI .. that's valuable additional information. There are numerous JsonPath implementations and numerous ways of using JsonPath. Perhaps you could update your question to describe (1) **exactly** how you are using JsonPath; (2) what JsonPath implementaiotn you are using, including its version; (3) how you are applying the JsonPath expression and (4) what result you want to get (e.g. do you want to get the JSON document after applying a given filter? or do you want to get a boolean answer to say whether a given filter is applicable?)

Comment: OK, I've added further information to the original post